# create a list by concatenating each individual string input with digits ranging from 1 to n. For output, a character must be capitalized

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

Example:

Input: i j k

Enter a value for n = 4

Output: I1 I2 I3 I4 J1 J2 J3 J4 K1 K2 K3 K4

I can't seem to separate the word and the number. I am getting

```
I 1 I 2 I 3 I 4 J 1 J 2 J 3 J 4 K 1 K 2 K 3 K 4
```

instead of

```
I1 I2 I3 I4 J1 J2 J3 J4 K1 K2 K3 K4
```

```
my_list = input("Input: ")
up_list = my_list.upper()
var =''
new_list2 = ""
lists = up_list.split()
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
for x in lists:
    for y in range(1, n+1):
        w = str(y)
        new_list = ('{}{}'.format(x, y))
        new_list2 += new_list
for i in new_list2:
    var += i
    var += " "
print(var)
```

Comment: `my_list` and `up_list` and `new_list2` are _strings_, not lists

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = input("Input: ").upper().split()
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
pairs = ' '.join(f'{s}{i}' for s in lst for i in range(1, n+1))
print(pairs)
# I1 I2 I3 I4 J1 J2 J3 J4 K1 K2 K3 K4
```

Answer (score -1):

`my_list` and `up_list` and `new_list2` are *strings*, not lists. In the interest of clarity, you should give your variables names that describe the purpose of the variable.

Also, you create each element of your output in `new_list`, then append it to the *string* `new_list2`, then iterate over each *character* of this string and append it to the string `var` with spaces between them. This makes no sense at all. Instead, you can simply create a *list* that you fill up in your nested loop, and then print that list separated by spaces using `str.join`, or by unpacking the list into the `print` function and specifying the separator.

Consider the following:

```
letters = input("Input: ").upper().split()
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))

result = []                 # Create an empty LIST
for letter in letters:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result.append(f"{letter}{i}")

print(" ".join(result))
# or
print(*result, sep=" ")
```

You can condense the nested loops into a list comprehension like so:

```
result = [f"{letter}{i}" for letter in letters for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

Or, if you only want to print this, you could just use the generator expression that drives the list comprehension as an argument to `str.join`:

```
print(" ".join(f"{letter}{i}" for letter in letters for i in range(1, n+1)))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
letters = input("Type letters:")
letters = letters.upper()
letter_list = letters.split(" ")

n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))  # assuming you will only input an integer here

for letter in letter_list:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(f"{letter}{i}", end=" ")
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to save the string for whatever reason, this will work too:

```
letters = input("Type letters:")
letters = letters.upper()
letter_list = letters.split(" ")

n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))

my_str = ""

for letter in letter_list:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        my_str += f"{letter}{i} "
print(my_str)
```

Comment: An answer that actually explains what OP did wrong is much more useful than a code dump

Answer (score -2):

In your second for loop:

```
for i in new_list2:
var += i
var += " "
```

you could do something like this so every other has the space instead:

```
for i in range(len(new_list2)):
var += new_list2[i]
    if i % 2 == 0:
       var += " "
```

Answer (score -2):

If I start from your code, the problem is due only to the two lines with `new_list2`. It should be a list (not a string), and values should be appended (not added). Here is the new code, very close to yours. However, you should really take care about the correspondence between the type and the name and each variable.

```
my_list = input("Input: ")
up_list = my_list.upper()
var =''
new_list2 = [] # instead of new_list2 = ""
lists = up_list.split()

n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))

for x in lists:
    for y in range(1, n+1):
        w = str(y)
        new_list = ('{}{}'.format(x, y))
        new_list2.append(new_list) # instead of new_list2 += new_list
for i in new_list2:
    print(i)
    var += i
    var += " "
print(var) # I1 I2 I3 I4 J1 J2 J3 J4 K1 K2 K3 K4
```

Other answers will give you more pyhtonic and optimized code.